# strtotime() function returning incorrect date

Tags: php, date, datetime, utc, strtotime

I am getting the date of the next week even when I have set the timezone to `UTC-9`.

When UTC changes the day i.e `16-03-2017 00:00:00`, and the UTC-9 timezone is still `15-03-2017 15:00:00`, `strtotime()` function returns the date of the next week.

```
$last_time_instance = strtotime(''Wednesday' ' 16:00:00);
```

The variable `$last_time_instance` returns the time correctly, but forwards the date to the next week i.e. `22-03-17`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: use date_default_timezone_set()  in the program.

Comment: should i use inside the strtotime() function?

Comment: On the top of your program, or right before `strtotime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append timezone `UTC-9` to the string:

```
$last_time_instance=strtotime('Wednesday 16:00:00 UTC-9');  // 1490803200

$time_instance_formatted=date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$last_time_instance);  // 29-03-2017 12:00:00
```

Comment: My apologies! I read these comments just now. I have ticked mark the answer. However I did upvote your answer. Many Thanks!